# How do I link to a custom form mode in a (node) tab?

Tags: nodes, forms, 10

My issue is my form is too big and too slow, with nested paragraphs, media entities and so on, the biggest issue is the metatag-module with its 100s of fields.

So I thought I just add a new form display mode, add the metatag-field only there and somehow link to it from some .links.tasks.yml with `base_route: entity.node.canonical`

Alas, it's apparently not that easy. I have no idea what route_name to use, if there even is any (but what good is a form mode if I can't use it?)

I could add a custom .routing.yml with

```
  defaults:
    _entity_form: node.metatags
```

but then, for that to work, I apparently need to somehow get it into the list of forms in Drupal\node\Entity\Node -> handlers -> form

Google is quite useless, because all I find are various examples about the display mode. quick_node_clone wasn't really helpfull as an example, because they also only use the default form mode.

Does anyone have any idea? This should be easy, if only I knew how...

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, since nobody seems to be answering questions around here anymore:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityFormDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_form_display_alter().
 */
function meta_tab_entity_form_display_alter(EntityFormDisplayInterface &$form_display, array $context) {

  if (isset($context['entity_type']) && isset($context['bundle'])) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository $entity_display_repo */
    $entity_display_repo = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');
    $form_mode_opts = $entity_display_repo->getFormModeOptionsByBundle($context['entity_type'], $context['bundle']);
    $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
    if ($route_name === "entity.node.metatags_form" && isset($form_mode_opts['metatag_form'])) {
      $form_display = $entity_display_repo->getFormDisplay($context['entity_type'], $context['bundle'], 'metatag_form');
    }else{
      $form_display = $entity_display_repo->getFormDisplay($context['entity_type'], $context['bundle'], 'default');
    }
  }
}

function meta_tab_entity_operation(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $operations = [];

  // Only add an operation for node entities.
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() !== 'node') {
    return $operations;
  }

  if (!_quick_node_clone_has_clone_permission($entity)) {
    return $operations;
  }

  $operations['metatags'] = [
    'title' => t('Metatags'),
    'weight' => '100',
    'url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node.metatags_form', ['node' => $entity->id()]),
  ];

  return $operations;
}
```

more or less copied from https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_form_mode/, obviously + routing.yml-file and links.task.yml

yes, it's ugly and hardcoded to machine_name = metatags_form, but at least it works. I can't spend another day on some minor taks that would have taken 30 minutes in the good old drupal7 days. I'm really getting sick of this over engineered piece of **** and Symfony.